# How to pass django rest framework response to html?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to pass django restframework response for any request to html.
Example: A list which contains objects, and html be articles.html.

I tried by using rest framework Response :

```
data= {'articles': Article.objects.all() }
return Response(data, template_name='articles.html')
```

I am getting this error :

```
""" AssertionError at /articles/

.accepted_renderer not set on Response """
```

Where i went wrong, please suggest me.

Comment: The link above does not work, but this one should:  http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/

Answer (score 53):

If it's a function based view, you made need to use an @api_view decorator to display properly.  I've seen this particular error happen for this exact reason (missing API View declaration in function based views).

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
# ....

@api_view(['GET', 'POST', ])
def articles(request, format=None):
    data= {'articles': Article.objects.all() }
    return Response(data, template_name='articles.html')
```

Answer (score 9):

In my case just forgot to set @api_view(['PUT']) on view function.

> So, 
>   **.accepted_renderer**
>  The renderer instance that will be used to render the response not set for view.
>   Set automatically by the APIView or @api_view immediately before the response is returned from the view.

Answer (score 4):

Have you added `TemplateHTMLRenderer` in your settings?

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#setting-the-renderers

Answer (score 1):

You missed `TemplateHTMLRenderer` decorator:

```
@api_view(('GET',))
@renderer_classes((TemplateHTMLRenderer,))
def articles(request, format=None):
    data= {'articles': Article.objects.all() }
    return Response(data, template_name='articles.html')
```

Comment: I keep getting a TypeError: <Model> is not JSON serializable.  Everything appears to be exactly as you suggest.